# What are the advantages of using Spring Integration style within Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm tasked with the requirement of using Spring Cloud Stream (with Kafka bindings). Going through Spring Cloud Stream's [Quick Start](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/#quick-start) and judging from the Config file it uses, [LogSinkConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/log/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-log/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/log/sink/LogSinkConfiguration.java), it seems the recommendation here is to use Spring Integration patterns, e.g. `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT)` to connect to the input channel. However all the tutorials I've found are using a different set of annotations from the Spring Cloud Stream library (vs Spring Integration), i.e. `@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)` in [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-stream) walk-through.

So which is better/newer/preferred (i.e. what's the "best practice"). Should I use the S.I. way of configuring the sink using `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Sink.INPUT)` or the alternative `@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)`. Are these two methods of hooking up the sink virtually the same, or are there advantages to using one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 2.0 we introduced spring-cloud-function support and with the imminent release of 3.0 we are now fully committed to functional support over any annotation driven (Spring Integration included).

So, to answer your question, functional support is the preferred way. Here is the [link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-stream.adoc#spring_cloud_function) to more info and feel free to follow up with more concrete questions.

Comment: Thanks. So the functional style supersedes the annotation style (i.e. @StreamListener), but what about using SI solely, i.e. using @ServiceActivator. Are there use-cases to completely bypass Spring Cloud Stream and just use the SI abstraction? How about if I want to integrate with a non-messaging input and send to a Messaging output. Is it necessary in this case to just go with SI and let it do the Spring Cloud Stream under-the-hood so to speak?

Comment: For that purpose you need to use an `IntegraitonFlows.from(Function.class)` or some `Function` extension interface: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-gateway

Comment: Ok, I see that. So, then a) why is the starter project using `@ServiceActivator` as the canonical example of Spring Cloud Stream (see `org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.log.sink.LogSinkConfiguration`) and b) are there any use-cases where `@ServiceActivator` is required?

Comment: The example were created a while back. `@ServiceActivator` just like `@StreamListener` and just like function support is just a way to configure your application. The advantage of functional approach is you only need Java to implement it and we'll take care of the rest. With ServiceActivator you need to know a bit about Spring Integration and Messaging and the same goes for StreamListener. But at the end of the day you choose what fits you. And no there are no use cases where ServiceActivator or StreamListener or function is required. You choose